# Openshift Origin Security best practices

Tags: security, kubernetes, openshift, iptables, openshift-origin

I installed an openshift origin 3.11 cluster last week and I have already encountered 2 security related issues.
(The servers only have 1 public accessible network interface)
Dnsmasq was being used to conduct DDoS reflection/
amplification attacks and so was the portmapper service.

Openshift does set up iptables rules to make the cluster work and I thank these rules assured the security of the cluster itself but with the 2 issues proved me wrong.

I resolved this 2 issues by firewalling access to port 53 and 111 and granting all access between nodes in the cluster
but I'm not sure if this is enough.

Do you have any best practice/rules to add in order to make an openshift cluster safe and am I supposed to edit the iptables rules since they have been set up by openshift itself?

This is the output of my iptables -L of the master-etc node so far and honestly I found this rules a little too permissive but since I'm not an iptables and openshift pro I'm not sure if I'm ok with them.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
KUBE-NODEPORT-NON-LOCAL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* Ensure that non-local NodePort traffic can flow */
KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes externally-visible service portals */
OPENSHIFT-FIREWALL-ALLOW  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* firewall overrides */
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  node2.domain.com      anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  node1.domain.com      anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  master.domain.com       anywhere            
OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
KUBE-FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding rules */
OPENSHIFT-ADMIN-OUTPUT-RULES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* administrator overrides */
OPENSHIFT-FIREWALL-FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* firewall overrides */

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             node2.domain.com     
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             node1.domain.com     
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             master.domain.com      

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain KUBE-FIREWALL (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets */ mark match 0x8000/0x8000

Chain KUBE-FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding rules */ mark match 0x1/0x1
ACCEPT     all  --  10.128.0.0/14        anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod source rule */ ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.128.0.0/14        /* kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod destination rule */ ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain KUBE-NODEPORT-NON-LOCAL (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain KUBE-SERVICES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.30.188.158       /* openshift-ansible-service-broker/asb:port-1337 has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:menandmice-dns reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.30.188.158       /* openshift-ansible-service-broker/asb:port-1338 has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:wmc-log-svc reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OPENSHIFT-ADMIN-OUTPUT-RULES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OPENSHIFT-FIREWALL-ALLOW (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:4789 /* VXLAN incoming */
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* from SDN to localhost */
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* from docker to localhost */

Chain OPENSHIFT-FIREWALL-FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  10.128.0.0/14        anywhere             /* attempted resend after connection close */ ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.128.0.0/14        /* forward traffic from SDN */
ACCEPT     all  --  10.128.0.0/14        anywhere             /* forward traffic to SDN */

Chain OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:10250
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:10256
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW udp dpt:4789
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpts:cslistener:ndmp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:jetcmeserver
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:2379
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:2380
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:pcsync-https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:pcsync-http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:senomix02
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW udp dpt:senomix02
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:EtherNet/IP-1
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:24007
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:24008
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpts:49152:49251
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:24010
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:iscsi-target
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:sunrpc
```

I would have changed the default policy in input to Drop on all compute nodes (node1 and node2) as a starter.

Comment: Better not touch the iptable rules(You may get network connectivity issue b/w pods & service). The openshift creates iptables to create `service`/`route` to map connection to actual pod with help of `kube-proxy`. If you want to secure the cluster, create firewall rules at gateway router.

Comment: Well, the master server here is going to be also the etcd and hence the gateway. This is a simple 3 node setup.
I ASSUME i could drop all except ssh and inter-comunication between nodes on compute nodes, i was wondering if someone has already solved this kind of problems and how he managed to secure the master/etcd